# Find the area of the quadrangular shaded region

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area, plane-geometry

> Calculate the area of the quadrangular shaded region ($S_3$),
> if $[S_1] = 18\ \mathrm{m}^2$, $[S_2] = 4.5\ \mathrm{m}^2$, and $MNCL$ is a parallelogram.
>
> [image]

(Answer: $27\ \mathrm{m}^2$)

[image]
(Drawing not to scale)

Some relations I found: If $BL$ passes through $T$ (meeting of the trapezoidal diagonals) then $AL = LC$
\begin{align*}
S_{ABL}&=S_{BLC},\\
S_{BMN}&=\frac{S_{ABC}}{4},\\
S_{AML}&=S_{MBN}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Why is AL=LC? The only restriction is that we have a parallelogram $MLNC$, so we could have chosen $L$ to be anywhere on $AC$, and then determine points $M, N$ after that.

Comment: Can you upload the original image?

Comment: @ACB No problem...The area of the shaded quadrangular region is not well defined but I confirmed it with someone who owns the book which is the one I highlighted here in my figure

Comment: @CalvinLin  Using Ceva's theorem : $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle MBN\\AM=a,MB=b. BN=kb,NC=ka, AL = x,LC=y\\a.bk.y=b.ak.x \implies  x= y$

Comment: @ACB  I believe that with an area of S2 = 4.5 the problem would not be solved, maybe it would be 1.5

Comment: @ACB Would a general solution be possible as a function of S1, S2 and S3?

Comment: I couldn't find a way yet. I'll try.

Comment: Why do you say $S_3$ is square ? It should have 4 right angles... It is a (concave) quadrilateral, that's all.

Comment: @JeanMarie..Sorry...There was a problem with the translation

Comment: @petaarantes:  If it's true that $\overline{AN}$, $\overline{BL}$, $\overline{CM}$ concur at $T$, then (as you've noted) $L$ is the midpoint of $\overline{AC}$. In that case, I find that the areas are related by
$$4 S_1 S_2 + 6 S_2 S_3 - 9 S_3^2 = 0$$
(which is independent of the location of $P$ and $Q$). However, for $(S_1,S_2)=(18,9/2)$, we get $S_3=\frac32\left(1\pm\sqrt{17}\right)=\{7.6846\ldots,-4.6846\ldots\}$. Are you sure you have identified the correct quadrangular region $S_3$?

Comment: @Blue  Your general formula is correct. Whoever provided the quadrangular area had the book but unfortunately these Peruvian problems (which are challenging) have many errors and sometimes we need to find their error to reach the solution. The other options would be, $25, 28, 22.5, 30m^2$

Comment: @Blue  I believe there was an error in some of the areas provided. $S1$ cannot be $4S2$